# How to connect to an Oracle 11g databse using Datagrip

Tags: oracle, datagrip

Suppose I have these lines (the host addresses are random) in my `tnsnames.ora` file that stores login information for a database in Oracle 11g.

```
mydb = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 152.126.178.13)(PORT = 1521)) 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 152.126.178.14)(PORT = 1521)) 
    (LOAD_BALANCE = no) 
    (FAILOVER = ON) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
      (SERVICE_NAME = newods1) 
      (FAILOVER_MODE = 
        (TYPE = SELECT) 
        (METHOD = BASIC) 
      ) 
    ) 
  )
```

I can use this file to connect to the database with PLSQL Developer. However, how do I do that with Datagrip? I tried using one of the template oracle data source in Datagrip where I only have to specify the user name, password, database name, IP address, but it didn't work.

A further question: is the `tnsnames.ora` file mandatory or can I use other ways to specify login parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by this [article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203526830-Connect-Datagrip-to-Oracle-using-TNS), I figured out the answer.

In the "Data Sources and Drivers" window:

- Download the oracle database driver.
- In the "General" -> "URL" section, choose "TNS" from the drop box.
- Specify the tns file path in the "TNSADMIN" section, and other necessary information below.

Example:

[image]